# No module named ‘points.datasets’ oder points

Tags: deep-learning, gpytorch

i am tried to implement this model https://github.com/rusty1s/pytorch_geometric/blob/master/benchmark/points/point_cnn.py on 3D Mesh Faust dataset. However, this failure occurs and i could not solve by !pip intall "package". can i get help thank you.

Comment: Can you describe which package are you trying to install, what command you used and what error did you get.

Comment: pytorch geometric, i tried to replicate the experiment of point cloud in that "point" link.

Comment: Can you paste the command (the one you ran) and the output you get.